# Sed and Regular Expression

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I've this issue: I've a CSV file that contains some data in this format:

```
100,30,1.704,,7
101,,suka,,5
```

and I should import this CSV inside mysql table

As you can seen, this csv has empty fields, denoted by double commas ',,' . I want using sed and regular expression, define  pattern **,,** and if it's matched substituing it with number **58** inside my csv file .
Anyone can help me, I don't knwo regex very well.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to first parse the CSV file and then replace empty fields with the number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
sed ':a;s/,,/,58,/g;ta' file
```

Comment: Could you explain what the `:a` and `;ta` mean?

Comment: `:a` is a label and `ta` means branch to the label `:a` if the previous substitution was successful. See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Programming-Commands).

Answer (score 1):

something like this should do the trick:

```
sed -e 's/,,/,58,/g'
```

which will search ('s') or ',,' and replace it by ',58,' for all occurences ('g'; as opposed to only the first occurence))

Comment: It wouldn't work with following line `101,,,suka,,5`. I think positive look-ahead would be a better approach for that special case. Perhaps the OP doesn't need it.

Answer (score 0):

In Vi editor ,go to command mode and type the below:

```
:%s/,,/,58,/g
```

Answer (score -1):

You may try using notepad++ if you want regex options. Open Search and replace set the search mode as "Regular Expressions" replace `,,` with `,58`. I just tried it and it works... `,,,,,,,,` to `,58,58,58,58`

Comment: Not only would this change `"101,,suka,,5"` to `"101,58suka,585"`, this question is for regular expressions in sed, not notepad++.